# SQL: Incorrect count on Null column

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL SQL is not returning the correct count for records that have null and not null values

I have the following values in a table with three columns (code,amt,name)

```
"AMPF";"0.1000";"Amplify Inc";
"AMPF";"0.1000";"Amplify Inc";
"AMPF";"0.2000";"Amplify Inc";
"AMPF";"0.2000";"Amplify Inc";
"AMPF";"0.3000";"Amplify Inc";
"AMPF";"0.3000";"";
"AMPF";"0.4000";"";
"XYZA";"0.1000";"PeterPal Inc";
"XYZA";"0.1000";"PeterPal Inc"
```

I am running the following query to pick up the number of records that exist for a particular item code.
SELECT code, name, count(amt) as cnt FROM table group by code order by cnt desc limit 30

```
SELECT code, name, count(amt) as cnt FROM table group by code order by cnt desc limit 30
```

Ideally, the expected result should be:

```
AMPF,Amplify Inc,7
XYZA,PeterPal Inc,2
```

But instead, it is resulting in:

```
AMPF,Amplify Inc,5
XYZA,PeterPal Inc,2
```

It indicates that although I am taking the count on amt column, it is somehow taking it on name column which is null in record numbers 6 and 7. 
Any thoughts on what is going wrong in my code?

Comment: Please always tag the DBMS you are using !

Comment: Your group by should not working unless it is MySQL with only full group by disabled.

Comment: sorry...this is MySQL

Answer (score 0):

First, just use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT code, MAX(name) as name, count(*) as cnt
FROM table 
GROUP BY code 
ORDER BY cnt desc 
LIMIT 30;
```

What is happening is that the values that look like `'AMPF'` are not really `'AMPF'` -- that is, they are not equal.  I don't know why.  It could be spaces at the beginning of the code, it could be "look-alike" characters in different character sets, it could be hidden characters.

If you look further down the list, you should see the other codes being counted -- if you leave out the `LIMIT`.

I also changed the `SELECT` so `NAME` is not taken from an indeterminate row.  This simply uses the `MAX()` value found.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. However, count(*) or even count(1) is not working. I manually verified each value and updated it to 'AMPF', but still no luck. Additionally, the "select * from table where code='AMPF'" returns 7 rows, so still not sure why it is reporting only 5 in the above SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this condition does not have a straightforward answer. By design, MySQL count() function actually counts ONLY the NOT NULL values. However, there are the following two workarounds that can be implemented:

First, One can run a separate SQL statement to count the records which are NULL.

Second, if one (or more) of the desired values are available in another table through a foreign key, pick up those values from the other table, and run a count on first table to get the correct count.

PS: I used the first one for my needs.